Missing `Kernel.php` file in Laravel project
I'm currently working on a Laravel project and I've encountered an issue where my Kernel.php file seems to be missing from the app/Http directory.
Here are the details:

Laravel Version: 5.8.3
Problem: Cannot locate Kernel.php in app/Http
Symptoms: Getting a 419 Page Expired error when trying to log in as a teacher

What I've tried so far:

Searched the app/Http directory thoroughly.
Checked my version control (Git) history to see if it was accidentally deleted or moved.
Compared my project structure with a standard Laravel installation but still can't locate the file.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? How can I restore or recreate the Kernel.php file?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
i have tried composer install still not there i even createe a new project still not there

In the Laravel 5.8, the app/Http/Kernel.php code you can copy/check on github, then it is referenced in the bootstrap/app.php, check the code in github.

I had the same issue in Laravel 11.35.1. In this version, the directory of Kernel.php is:
YourProjectName\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php

